# Can any user read the coding as they're .js plain text files?

Tags: javascript, winjs

I'm a C# developer, and use XAML for user interfaces. Lately I've been wondering something regarding HTML5+JavaScript development (used in Universal Windows App development, as well as for websites). Javascript is compiled and executed at run-time on the client device. So any user can go into the folder where they're stored on computer, and see all the code in it, right?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the title question is, simply, "yes," and the question in the post is "because <use-cases>." The first not terribly useful, the second purely opinion based speculation (pending an exhaustive poll of all developers).

Comment: So you want me to remove the question "why do developers use such framework" and post it as a separate question? Alright. I'll edit it.

Comment: This question is no longer opinion-based, so I voted to reopen.  I don't think the question is useful, though.  Do you have an actual, non-opinion problem you'd rather ask about?

Answer (score 1):

There is no unreadable alternative for js and html5. That's why so many websites are so slow in adopting html5 video and replacing adobe flash.

But if your entire application is client side and you worry about your code being stolen you're doing something wrong. Almost any application requires serverside code that isn't accessible.

And it doesn't matter anyway, who cares about some js that makes a div draggable or moves some html around.

Comment: Oh I see. I'm not sure if people develop pure HTML5+Javascript+CSS websites without any server-side coding, but the Universal Windows Application developed using HTML5+Javascript and purely client-side, afaik.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think readable javascript code is of any value...what matters is the server side code like php or ASP which really matters in the security of the websites

And even if the developer didnt want the user to read the javascript framework.. what option does he/she have to prevent it..?**none!**

Comment: Nah they can keep using adobe flash in websites(bad idea).

Comment: Most of the phones doesnt support flash...hell even most of the computers doesnt have adobe flash installed!

Comment: Nah flash argument on phones is correct but on computers is bs, just check the google chrome userbase(has flash built in).

Comment: I disagree even though chrome has built in flash most people just disable it bcos its a data sucker and chrome is not the only browser  which people use...

Comment: Ask a random user how it can be disabled and they don't even know...Even I don't know it from the top of my head.

Comment: And nobody cares about data on a computer, internet with data limits are ancient history.

Answer (score 0):

The client side code is indeed visible by the client. If something is available client side, then you won't need a round trip to the server to get it.

For example you could imagine a simple calculator application. You could write it client-side, in Javascript, the app can ouptut the calculations immediately. Or you could write it server-side (in wathever language you want), which means you need to ask the server for the calculation (with an ajax request probably), and wait for it to respond.

Also some things doesn't make sense on the server-side. Pretty much any action that changes the DOM, which only exists client-side, in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote about this on my blog a while back, see [Protecting Your Code](http://www.kraigbrockschmidt.com/2013/04/04/protecting-your-code/), 
as an addendum to my free ebook, [Programming Windows Store Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, 2nd Edition](http://aka.ms/BrockschmidtBook2).

The short of it is that JS code it not protected, though you can make things a little more difficult with minification/uglification like many website authors do. You can also take steps by putting some of the code you care about into Windows Runtime Components written in C++ (C# can be decompiled). The only really secure solution is to have code on a server, and draw from that in an app which of course doesn't work for all cases, but is an option.

Note that some of my comments in that blog from 3 years ago might be a little dated. I believe that current Windows Store policy now allows you to load code from a remote server at run time.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for the link. I'll check our your blog post.